# Electrum: 2 Wallets showing same Transactions

Tags: wallet, electrum, seed

I hope someone can explain, if it's dangerous that i have 2 wallets and both showing the same transactions, the first one has a password for the seed and i can't remember it, the second one not. I also can't remember what i have done and why i have 2 wallets.

If someone can explain me what to do or/and how i can setup a new fresh password-protectet wallet in electrum with all my transactions, would be great.
This would help me to achieve a better technical-understanding for bitcoin and electrum-wallet.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only important thing is the seed (the *seed words*). With it, you can create copies of the Electrum-wallet **with or without** password. So you could have the same wallet on a PC desktop **without** password and on an Android phone **with** a password. (Note that the Android-client also forces you to enter a PIN code.)

I assume you created a new Electrum-wallet, password-protected it and then imported the same Electrum-wallet again (using the seed), without password. You can safely delete the one with password as long as you are **very** sure they are indeed the same. Perhaps double-check the different **Addresses** (both Receiving and Change) before you do this. (But this might be hard since you forgot the password?) As long as you are sure you only have **one seed** that you used for both wallets, you can safely delete one of them. They are surely the same wallet.

Comment: thank you sir, it is kind a more clear now. i have to test some things without much bitcoins involved in this 2 wallets i think.

Comment: The point is. The SEED is the MASTER. Once you enter it (and hopefully you wrote it down somewhere) you can put an extra password on it.. Probably just to protect from those who have access to your computer. But the SEED is the REAL DEAL. PROTECT IT WITH YOUR LIFE :)

Comment: Yes, would throw some Föiflieber (5.- swiss Frank-coins) to the Atackers Head!